# Concerning an ideal invariant under an involution

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, modules, involutions

The following is a variation on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3350625/ideal-of-kx-y-invariant-under-an-involution) question (or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3348288/p-s-1k-1-q-s-2k-2-in-kx-y-such-that-s-1-k-1-s-2-k-2-in-langle-p-q-ran?noredirect=1&lq=1) question).

Let $\beta: k[x,y] \to k[x,y]$ be the following involution $\beta: (x,y) \mapsto (x,-y)$, namely, $\beta$ is an automorphism of order two.
Denote the set of symmetric elements w.r.t $\beta$ by $S_{\beta}$ and the set of
skew-symmetric elements w.r.t $\beta$ by $K_{\beta}$.

Let $s_1,s_2 \in S_{\beta}$ and $k_1,k_2 \in K_{\beta}$.
Write $p=s_1+k_1$ and $q=s_2+k_2$.
Denote the ideal generated by $p$ and $q$ by $I$, $I= \langle p,q \rangle$.

Assume that $s_1,s_2,k_1,k_2 \in I$.

> Should $\{s_1,s_2\}$ or $\{k_1,k_2\}$ be algebraically dependent?
>   (see the comments in the linked question).

Clearly, $I$ is an invariant $k$-subspace, but I do not see how this helps.
Perhaps [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.0056) paper is relevant.

**Edit:** We can define $G:=\{1,\beta\}$ ($G$ is a group) and then $I$ is $G$-invariant.
See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/318736/ideals-invariant-under-ring-automorphisms) question.

**Edid 2:** Observe that, for example, we do not know if $J:=\langle p^2,q \rangle \subset I$ is invariant under $\beta$.

Any comments and hints are welcome!
Now I have asked this question at [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/345448/an-ideal-invariant-under-an-automorphism).